# Why is Object.assign not replacing a key in my new object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

**Function handleSave**

```
@bind
private handleSave() {
  const { coin, balance } = this.state;
  console.log('coin', coin);
  console.log('balance', balance);

  const updatedCoin = Object.assign({
    ...coin,
    position: balance
  }, coin);

  console.log('updatedCoin', updatedCoin);
  this.props.updateCoinPortfolio(updatedCoin);
  this.props.toggle(false);
}
```

At the first console.log `coin` is the following object:

```
{
  availableSupply: "17572412",
  currency: "BTC",
  exchange: "",
  exchange_base: "",
  marketCap: 67651096742.34,
  name: "Bitcoin",
  percentage: 100,
  position: 1,
  price: "3849.84695",
  value: 3849.84695
}
```

And `balance = 2`

Next during this log: `console.log('updatedCoin', updatedCoin);` I expect the position of coin to now be `2` and not `1`. But it is still `1`?

[image: a]

**The Object.assign part:**

```
const updatedCoin = Object.assign({
  ...coin,
  position: balance
}, coin);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use it this way to get it work:

```
const updatedCoin = Object.assign({}, coin, {position: balance});
```

The way you was using it, you first generate an object with the original coin object plus the updated position. This would be enough to get your updated object, like shown on next example:

```js
let coin = {
  availableSupply: "17572412",
  currency: "BTC",
  exchange: "",
  exchange_base: "",
  marketCap: 67651096742.34,
  name: "Bitcoin",
  percentage: 100,
  position: 1,
  price: "3849.84695",
  value: 3849.84695
}

console.log({...coin, position: 2});
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

But later and finally you assign back all the original coin properties to the updated object, getting back your starting object:

```js
let coin = {
  availableSupply: "17572412",
  currency: "BTC",
  exchange: "",
  exchange_base: "",
  marketCap: 67651096742.34,
  name: "Bitcoin",
  percentage: 100,
  position: 1,
  price: "3849.84695",
  value: 3849.84695
}

let updated = {...coin, position: 2};
console.log(Object.assign(updated, coin));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Comment: Thanks for the demo! 3 mins :D

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing metaphors. You *either* want `assign`:

```
const updatedCoin = Object.assign({}, coin, {position: balance});
```

*or* property spread:

```
const updatedCoin = {
  ...coin,
  position: balance
};
```

Your `assign` code didn't work because you put `coin` *after* the object you updated, so `position` got overwritten from `coin`. (With `assign` — and spread — it's the last one that wins.)

Answer (score 2):

You need do like this:

> const updatedCoin = Object.assign({ ...coin, position: balance}, {});

or more simple:

> const updatedCoin = { ...coin, position: balance }

Answer (score 1):

Just do :

```
const updatedCoin = {
  ...coin,
  position: balance
}
```

With your code, you're first merging `coin` with `{position: balance}` but then with `assign` you're overwriting your `{position: balance}` with `coin`'s value for `position`.